# Can I use datasource=.\\SQLEXPRESS or do I need to now use: machinename\\SQLEXPRESS

Tags: c#, string, connection, sql-server-2008-express

Can I still use datasource=.\SQLEXPRESS or do I need to change it to : machine_name\SQLEXPRESS  for a local instance of SQL Server 2008 Express in C#?

My connection string worked fine in SQL Express 2005, but with the same settings no longer works for 2008.

Comment: please don't put "SQL 2008 Express - C# - " in your title. Just leave that info in the tags.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming the instance name is indeed `SQLEXPRESS`, using `.\SQLEXPRESS` will work locally.

Use the [SQL Server Configuration Manager](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174212.aspx) to find out the correct instance name.

Comment: Could I create an alias in Configuration Manager and use that as my datasource in my connection string?

Comment: @user719825 - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/907851/change-sql-server-instance-name

Answer (score 0):

What is the final purpose of the app as it more conventional to include pc name.