# ASP.NET Core 2.1 Where to find database after performing migration

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have just started a new .net core project and created my first migration and updated the database locally.

How can I view the table?

In my previous ASP.NET MVC project, I could connect to .\SQLExpress in Visual Studio and the database would open up.

This is my connection string

```
"DefaultConn": "Server=.\\SQLEXPRESS;Database=ManagementStudio-7661DEE4-C53F-4E49-B140-2AFAA2C85927;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true"
```

How can I also convert this into a username password thing?

Sorry, I'm new to .net core

EDIT: I can confirm that the db and tables were created. When I run update-database again, I get errors that say they already exist.

Comment: Do you have the mdf file ?

Comment: Open up SQL Server Object Explorer pane in Visual Studio. Exand the instances there until you see you database.

Comment: No. I tried looking and nothing appeared. Doesn't seem like its creating a localdb

Comment: In your project there have folder like Migration in that folder you get the migrations that you run.

Comment: I'm looking for a way to see the db tables and the data. Also, I opened up the Server Object Explorer pane and it shows Data Connections. Its empty.

Comment: Server Explorer != SQL Server Object Explorer. Perhaps the wrong view?

Comment: Nothing in the SQL Server Object Explorer as well. It just says SQL Server and then when i expand it, it doesnt show my db

Comment: Have you tried `SQL Server Object Explorer` -> `SQL Server` -> right-click + `Add SQL Server` ?

Comment: @PeterB Yeah I tried that. Can't find it there as well. Not sure where it went

Comment: I have the sql servermanagement studio and can't find it there as well

Comment: I just found it. For some reason, the db was named config. I think one of my settings is wrong. Thank you for all your help.

Answer (score 4):

Dot (`.`) means the local machine. `SQLEXPRESS` is the name of your `SQL Express` default instance. So the same server as `.\SQLEXPRESS` is `(local)\SQLEXPRESS`

Use [SQL Server Management Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/sql-server-configuration-manager) (`SSMS`) free tool to connect to your local `DB` server instance with `Windows Authentication` (I assume your Windows account has all needed rights on your local machine). You can also use [SQL Server Configuration Manager](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/sql-server-configuration-manager) tool as an alternative.

See also relevant topic [Can I use datasource=.\SQLEXPRESS or do I need to now use: machinename\SQLEXPRESS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6139299/can-i-use-datasource-sqlexpress-or-do-i-need-to-now-use-machinename-sqlexpr)